# PyToch: ValueError: Expected input batch_size (256) to match target batch_size (128)

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, lstm, part-of-speech

I've faced a ValueError while training a BiLSTM part of speech tagger using pytorch. **ValueError: Expected input batch_size (256) to match target batch_size (128).**

```
def train(model, iterator, optimizer, criterion, tag_pad_idx):
    
    epoch_loss = 0
    epoch_acc = 0
    
    model.train()
    
    for batch in iterator:
        
        text = batch.p
        tags = batch.t
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        #text = [sent len, batch size]
        
        predictions = model(text)
        
        #predictions = [sent len, batch size, output dim]
        #tags = [sent len, batch size]
        
        predictions = predictions.view(-1, predictions.shape[-1])
        tags = tags.view(-1)
        
        #predictions = [sent len * batch size, output dim]
        #tags = [sent len * batch size]
        
        loss = criterion(predictions, tags)
                
        acc = categorical_accuracy(predictions, tags, tag_pad_idx)
        
        loss.backward()
        
        optimizer.step()
        
        epoch_loss += loss.item()
        epoch_acc += acc.item()
        
    return epoch_loss / len(iterator), epoch_acc / len(iterator)



def evaluate(model, iterator, criterion, tag_pad_idx):
    
    epoch_loss = 0
    epoch_acc = 0
    
    model.eval()
    
    with torch.no_grad():
    
        for batch in iterator:

            text = batch.p
            tags = batch.t
            
            predictions = model(text)
            
            predictions = predictions.view(-1, predictions.shape[-1])
            tags = tags.view(-1)
            
            loss = criterion(predictions, tags)
            
            acc = categorical_accuracy(predictions, tags, tag_pad_idx)

            epoch_loss += loss.item()
            epoch_acc += acc.item()
        
    return epoch_loss / len(iterator), epoch_acc / len(iterator)

class BiLSTMPOSTagger(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, 
                     input_dim, 
                     embedding_dim, 
                     hidden_dim, 
                     output_dim, 
                     n_layers, 
                     bidirectional, 
                     dropout, 
                     pad_idx):
            
            super().__init__()
            
            self.embedding = nn.Embedding(input_dim, embedding_dim, padding_idx = pad_idx)
            
            self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, 
                                hidden_dim, 
                                num_layers = n_layers, 
                                bidirectional = bidirectional,
                                dropout = dropout if n_layers > 1 else 0)
            
            self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim * 2 if bidirectional else hidden_dim, output_dim)
            
            self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
            
        def forward(self, text):
            embedded = self.dropout(self.embedding(text))
            outputs, (hidden, cell) = self.lstm(embedded)
            predictions = self.fc(self.dropout(outputs))        
            return predictions
```

...........................
...........................
...........................
...........................

```
INPUT_DIM = len(POS.vocab)
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100
HIDDEN_DIM = 128
OUTPUT_DIM = len(TAG.vocab)
N_LAYERS = 2
BIDIRECTIONAL = True
DROPOUT = 0.25
PAD_IDX = POS.vocab.stoi[POS.pad_token]

print(INPUT_DIM)  #output 22147
print(OUTPUT_DIM) #output 42

model = BiLSTMPOSTagger(INPUT_DIM, 
                        EMBEDDING_DIM, 
                        HIDDEN_DIM, 
                        OUTPUT_DIM, 
                        N_LAYERS, 
                        BIDIRECTIONAL, 
                        DROPOUT, 
                        PAD_IDX)
```

...........................
...........................
...........................
...........................

```
N_EPOCHS = 10

best_valid_loss = float('inf')

for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):

    start_time = time.time()
    
    train_loss, train_acc = train(model, train_iterator, optimizer, criterion, TAG_PAD_IDX)
    valid_loss, valid_acc = evaluate(model, valid_iterator, criterion, TAG_PAD_IDX)
    
    end_time = time.time()

    epoch_mins, epoch_secs = epoch_time(start_time, end_time)
    
    if valid_loss < best_valid_loss:
        best_valid_loss = valid_loss
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'tut1-model.pt')
    
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch+1:02} | Epoch Time: {epoch_mins}m {epoch_secs}s')
    print(f'\tTrain Loss: {train_loss:.3f} | Train Acc: {train_acc*100:.2f}%')
    print(f'\t Val. Loss: {valid_loss:.3f} |  Val. Acc: {valid_acc*100:.2f}%')





ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-83bf30366feb> in <module>()
      7     start_time = time.time()
      8 
----> 9     train_loss, train_acc = train(model, train_iterator, optimizer, criterion, TAG_PAD_IDX)
     10     valid_loss, valid_acc = evaluate(model, valid_iterator, criterion, TAG_PAD_IDX)
     11 

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2260     if input.size(0) != target.size(0):
   2261         raise ValueError('Expected input batch_size ({}) to match target batch_size ({}).'
-> 2262                          .format(input.size(0), target.size(0)))
   2263     if dim == 2:
   2264         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)

ValueError: Expected input batch_size (256) to match target batch_size (128).
```

Comment: can you please add the code of your train() and you evaluate() function? I guess the problem lies in train() when calculating the loss. Print the shapes of your predictions and your targets to check if they are the same

Comment: Also, a stack trace of the error would be much better. But I guess this error is thrown while calculating the loss.

Comment: @TheodorPeifer I just edited the question to include the training and evaluation functions. Thank you!!

Comment: @planet_pluto I included the stack trace. Thank you

Comment: could you print ```tags.shape``` and ```predictions.shape``` once before you apply ```.view()``` and once after?

Comment: @TheodorPeifer, Before applying .view():  predictions.shape = torch.Size([2, 128, 42])  and tags.shape = torch.Size([1, 128]) . After applying .view(): predictions.shape = torch.Size([256, 42])  and tags.shape = torch.Size([128]) Thank you.

Comment: Are your input tensors batch first or sequence length first?
If your input is `bs, sl, n`, then you need to pass `batch_first=True` to your LSTM. By default, `batch_first=False` and the LSTM expects tensors to be `sl, bs, n`

Answer (score 0):

*(continuing from the comments)*

I guess that your batch-size is equal to 128 (its nowhere defined), right?
The LSTM outputs a list of the outputs of every timestep. But for classification you normaly just want the last one. So the first dimension of `outputs` is your sequence length which in your case seems to be 2. And when you apply `.view` this two gets multiplied with your batch-size (128) and then it gets 256. So straight after your lstm layer you need to take the last output the the output-sequence `outputs`. Like this:

```py
def forward(self, text):
    embedded = self.dropout(self.embedding(text))
    outputs, (hidden, cell) = self.lstm(embedded)
    
    # take last output
    outputs = outputs.reshape(batch_size, sequence_size, hidden_size)
    outputs = outputs[:, -1]

    predictions = self.fc(self.dropout(outputs))        
    return predictions
```

Comment: You are right, my batch size is 128. I applied your code above and it shows  ValueError: Expected input batch_size (2) to match target batch_size (128). with  Predictions:  torch.Size([2, 42])
Tag  torch.Size([1, 128])
Prediction:  torch.Size([2, 42])
Tag:  torch.Size([128])

Comment: could you add batch_first=True as a parameter of the nn.LSTM function and try again?

Comment: hm, then maybe you have to reshape it, I edited my answer

Comment: It's still the same.

Comment: really? thats confusing. When you print  outputs,shape straight after the lstm layer it should be 2, 128, 42 right? Your goal is to take the last one of the two to get 1, 128, 42 and then reshape it to 128, 42. And then pass that into your dense layer which outputs 128,1. Try to archieve that, usually it should work with the steps above. (edit: also try to forget about the reshape and instead of [:, -1] use [-1])

Comment: Like outputs = outputs[-1] ? May be if it can help fixing the issue.. I adopted the code from  [link](https://github.com/bentrevett/pytorch-pos-tagging/blob/master/1%20-%20BiLSTM%20for%20PoS%20Tagging.ipynb) . The only changes are the embeddings ( I'm using fasttext pretrained embeddings) and the dataset.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that when I decrease the size of the dataset (like only the first 50 rows as a training set), it works fine.